# CSS underline text with number below line

Tags: javascript, html, css, underline

How can I underline text and add a small number underneath the underline like in this image using css, html, or javascript?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to where that is online, or is it just in Word or some other text editor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible using `:after` :pseudo-element.

```css
div {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
span {
  position: relative;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '2';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>over the <span>Triangle, a few months later,</span> another plane disappeared. A ship named the Sandra.</div>
```

---

If you want to set the `width` of the `div` to percentage units for responsiveness, you could avoid line break in `span` by setting `white-space: pre`.

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLt26dtx/2/)**</kbd>

In the example below, the `width` has been set to `25%` to demonstrate this.

```css
div {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 30px;
}
span {
  position: relative;
  white-space: pre;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '2';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>over the <span>Triangle, a few months later</span>, another plane disappeared. A ship named the Sandra.</div>
```

---

Also, you could use CSS's [`attr()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) function to fetch attribute values from the HTML element the :pseudo-element is added on.

```css
div {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
}
span {
  position: relative;
  white-space: pre;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-num);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>over the <span data-num="2">Triangle, a few months later</span>, another plane disappeared. A ship named the Sandra.</div>
```

Comment: Did you forget to add `top: 100%` to `span:after`?

Comment: Hm, does not look nice on Safari/Mac. Looks perfect in Chrome though. http://i.imgur.com/V2WbdtU.png

Comment: Just curious, is there any particular reason you use `width: auto; height: 15px;` on the `span`?

Comment: is it possible to make this work when resizing the page? The line moves around the paragraph and doesn't stick to the words

Comment: i'm changing the div that the text is in when the user resizes the page. and the text moves inside the div to fill it out completely. When that happens the line moves to different words.

Answer (score 2):

Using @chipChocolates answer, if you don't want to put the subscripts into the CSS style block, but rather use them in the body as you need them...

```css
div {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
span {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 15px;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(subscript-line);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>over the <span subscript-line="1">Triangle, a few months later</span>, another plane disappeared. A ship named the Sandra.</div>
<div>over the <span subscript-line="2">Triangle, a few months later</span>, another plane disappeared. A ship named the Sandra.</div>
<div>over the <span subscript-line="3">Triangle, a few months later</span>, another plane disappeared. A ship named the Sandra.</div>
```

Comment: Definitely the correct answer, hard coding content in CSS is not good if can be avoided - not sure on backwards compat (IE) with this though?

Comment: If the business rules allow, you could take the abstraction further and use a CSS counter for getting the subscript value.